# When a particular file arrives then execute a procedure using Shell Script

Tags: shell-script, files

When a particular file for eg: "abc.csv" file arrives into a directory for eg: "mydir", I need to execute a procedure using shell script.

*"There was a procedure which will load data from csv to table and once the process completed the source file will be ranamed as "filename"**_last**. Everyday may get more than one file with same name."*

In such case whenever the new file placed into directory need to execute the procedure using shell script on LINUX environment.

Comment: We are not a script writing service. Please provide a question for this Q&A site, by first stating what you did, then where you got stuck, including error messages, and then provide a useful question (sentence with question mark, preferably not something useless like "Can anyone help?")

Comment: Also, state the OS you are running.

Answer (score 4):

Use inotify-tools (http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait).

```
$ cat monitor_csv.sh
if (( $# == 0)); then
   echo "Usage $0 <directory-to-monitor>"
   exit 1
fi

DIR=$1
while true;
do
    res=$(inotifywait $DIR)
    echo "Get from inotifywait: "$res
    if test -f $DIR/abc.csv; then
        echo "lauching a procedure and breaking out of the loop"
        # bash ./run_procedure.sh
        break
    else
        echo "keep watching"
    fi
done

echo "finished"
```

This is an example:

```
$ ./monitor_csv.sh ./mydir
Setting up watches.  
Watches established.
Get from inotifywait: ./mydir/ CREATE abc2.csv
keep watching
Setting up watches.  
Watches established.
Get from inotifywait: ./mydir/ CREATE abc.csv
lauching a procedure and breaking out of the loop
finished
```

Some improvements to this script might be done:

1. Use a timeout with `inotifywait`:

   ```
      -t <seconds>, --timeout <seconds>
             Listen for an event for the specified amount of seconds, exiting if an event has not occurred in that time.
   ```
2. Specify exact event types

   ```
   inotifywait -e create -e moved_to ./mydir
   ```

The list of all events:

```
access      file or directory contents were read
modify      file or directory contents were written
attrib      file or directory attributes changed
close_write file or directory closed, after being opened in
            writeable mode
close_nowrite   file or directory closed, after being opened in
            read-only mode
close       file or directory closed, regardless of read/write mode
open        file or directory opened
moved_to    file or directory moved to watched directory
moved_from  file or directory moved from watched directory
move        file or directory moved to or from watched directory
create      file or directory created within watched directory
delete      file or directory deleted within watched directory
delete_self file or directory was deleted
unmount     file system containing file or directory unmounted
```